# (<unknown>): did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character while scanning an anchor at line 74 column 16

Tags: plugins, permissions, yaml, minecraft

(full file: http://pastebin.com/jpTn5wqH)

```
groups:
  Member:
    options:
      default: true
      prefix: '&f[&7Nomad&f]’
    permissions:
    - essentials.kits.Nomad
    - essentials.kit.Nomad
    - bungeechat.global
    - bungeecord.command.server
    - essentials.msg
    - essentials.message
    - towny.leave
    - essentials.mail
    - essentials.mail.send
    - essentials.warp.list
    - essentials.warp
    - libsdisguise.disguise.*
    - essentials.balancetop
    - essentials.balance
    - bukkit.command.plugins
    - towny.command.town.add
    - towny.claimed.owntown.build.*
    - ChestShop.shop.buy
    - ChestShop.shop.sell
    - ChestShop.shop.create
    - essentials.plugins
    - essentials.ping
    - essentials.rules
    - essentials.balance.others
    - MyPet.command.trade.offer
    - essentials.killall
    - bukkit.plugins
    - bukkit.plugin
    - essentials.kit.peasant
    - essentials.pay
    - ontime.player.*
    - towny.chat.town
    - towny.chat.general
    - towny.wild.*
    - towny.command.town.buy
    - towny.command.plot.claim
    - mcmmo.repair.*
    - essentials.ignore
    - essentials.money
    - essentials.help
    - essentials.build
    - essentials.list
    - essentials.help
    - essentials.kit
    - essentials.spawn
    - essentials.afk
    - essentials.r
    - essentials.respond
    - essentials.talk
    - essentials.home
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.tpaccept
    - essentials.tpask
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.sethome
    - essentials.delhome
    - auctions.command.start
    - auctions.command.info
    - auctions.command.queue
    - auctions.command.end
    - auctions.command.ignore
    - auctions.command.bid
    - auctions.command.cancel
    inheritance:
    - Member
  Builder:
    options:
      prefix: '&0[&2Builder&0]&r'
    inheritance:
    - Member
    permissions:
    - worldguard.region.bypass.world
    - essentials.gamemode.Adventure
    - essentials.gamemode.survival
    - essentials.gamemode.spectator
    - essentials.gamemode.creative
    - essentials.mute
    - essentials.gamemode.others
    - essentials.gamemode.*
    - essentials.gamemode
    - worldedit.*
  Head Builder:
    options:
      prefix: '&r[&aHead Builder&r]&r'    # line 74
    inheritance:
    - Builder
    - Member
    - King
```

Perms For PermX Minecraft Plugin

What is wrong with the file?

Answer (score 2):

Your YAML file starts with:

```
groups:
  Member:
    options:
      default: true
      prefix: '&f[&7Nomad&f]’
    permissions:
    - essentials.kits.Nomad
    - essentials.kit.Nomad
```

and around line 74 has:

```
  Builder:
    options:
      prefix: '&0[&2Builder&0]&r'
    inheritance:
    - Member
    permissions:
    - worldguard.region.bypass.world
    - essentials.gamemode.Adventure
```

The line:

```
prefix: '&f[&7Nomad&f]’
```

starts a string (with the `'`) that ends on the line 74 followed by an unexpected character. You most likely want to change the `’` at the end of that line 5, as it is probably a typo and should be `'`.

With that change the file parses correctly.